# Java and Algebra

Tags: java, math, geometry, distance, algebra

I'm making a program that will find a fraction of the distance between two points from a point. The Problem is, is that I need an algorithm to find the X distance between two points as well as the Y distance, not just the straight distance in itself.

```
For example, 2/3 the distance from A to B. (A and B being on a graph)

try {    
                String a;
                a = x1_tf.getText().toString();
                double x1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                a = y1_tf.getText().toString();
                double y1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                a = x2_tf.getText().toString();
                double x2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                a = y2_tf.getText().toString();
                double y2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                double Ax,Ay, x = 0,y = 0,nx,ny,fx = 0,fy = 0;
                double numerator = Integer.parseInt(fracx_tf.getText().toString());
                double denominator = Integer.parseInt(fracy_tf.getText().toString());

                if(fromwhat_combobox.getSelectedIndex()==0) {
                    Ax = Integer.parseInt(x1_tf.getText().toString());
                    Ay = Integer.parseInt(y1_tf.getText().toString());

                    //problem below
                    x += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2));
                    y += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2));
                    //problem lies here ^^^^
                }
                else {
                    Ax = Integer.parseInt(x2_tf.getText().toString());
                    Ay = Integer.parseInt(y2_tf.getText().toString());

                    //problem below
                    x += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2));
                    y += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2));
                    //problem lies here ^^^^
                }

                nx = (x*numerator)/denominator;
                ny = (y*numerator)/denominator;
                fx = Ax + nx;

                if((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)>=0) {
                    fy = Ay + ny;
                }
                else {
                    fy = Ay - ny;
                }

                String answer = "("+fx+","+fy+") is "+numerator+"/"+denominator+" way from ";
                output_pane.setText(answer);
            }catch(Exception e){}
```

All of the other code works fine, I just need help with an algorithm that finds the distance between two points on the x-grid as well as the y-grid. The only thing I can think of is a complicated for-loop or a giant nest of if loops.

JUST TO CLARIFY :

fromwhat_combobox is a selection of what point to use, IE, 2/5 the distance from which point, Ax and Ay represent the coordinates of that point. The rest is easy to figure.

Complete code...

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

public class DistanceBetweenPointsCALC extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public DistanceBetweenPointsCALC() {
        initComponents();  //default init components
        cinitComponents(); // custom init components
        oinitComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        calc_button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        output_pane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        y1_tf = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        x2_tf = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        y2_tf = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        x1_tf = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        frac_checkbox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        fromwhat_combobox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        fracx_tf = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        fracy_tf = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        calc_button.setText("Calc");

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(output_pane);

        y1_tf.setText("Y1");

        x2_tf.setText("X2");

        y2_tf.setText("Y2");

        x1_tf.setText("X1");

        frac_checkbox.setText("Fraction of the Distance");

        fromwhat_combobox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "From X1", "From X2" }));

        fracx_tf.setText("frac x");

        fracy_tf.setText("frac y");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(calc_button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 156, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(x2_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 75, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(x1_tf))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(y1_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 75, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(y2_tf))))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(fromwhat_combobox, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(fracy_tf)
                            .addComponent(fracx_tf)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(frac_checkbox)
                        .addGap(0, 254, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(x1_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(y1_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(fromwhat_combobox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(x2_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(y2_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(fracx_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(calc_button)
                    .addComponent(fracy_tf, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(frac_checkbox)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 129, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void cinitComponents() {

        calc_button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                calc_buttonAP(evt);
            }
        });

        frac_checkbox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                frac_checkboxAP(evt);
            }
        });

        fracx_tf.setEnabled(false);
        fracy_tf.setEnabled(false);
        fromwhat_combobox.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void oinitComponents() {
        x1_tf.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {
            String DEFAULT_TEXT = "X1";
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
                String s = x1_tf.getText();
                if(s.equals(DEFAULT_TEXT)) { x1_tf.selectAll(); }
            }
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String s = x1_tf.getText();
                if(s.length()<=0) { x1_tf.setText("X1"); }
            }
        });

        y1_tf.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {
            String DEFAULT_TEXT = "Y1";
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
                String s = y1_tf.getText();
                if(s.equals(DEFAULT_TEXT)) { y1_tf.selectAll(); }
            }
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String s = y1_tf.getText();
                if(s.length()<=0) { y1_tf.setText("Y1"); }
            }
        });

        x2_tf.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {
            String DEFAULT_TEXT = "X2";
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
                String s = x2_tf.getText();
                if(s.equals(DEFAULT_TEXT)) { x2_tf.selectAll(); }
            }
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String s = x2_tf.getText();
                if(s.length()<=0) { x2_tf.setText("X2"); }
            }
        });

        y2_tf.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {
            String DEFAULT_TEXT = "Y2";
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
                String s = y2_tf.getText();
                if(s.equals(DEFAULT_TEXT)) { y2_tf.selectAll(); }
            }
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String s = y2_tf.getText();
                if(s.length()<=0) { y2_tf.setText("Y2"); }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*Look and feel set to Windows*/
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DistanceBetweenPointsCALC.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DistanceBetweenPointsCALC.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DistanceBetweenPointsCALC.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DistanceBetweenPointsCALC.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DistanceBetweenPointsCALC().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public static javax.swing.JButton calc_button;
    public static javax.swing.JCheckBox frac_checkbox;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField fracx_tf;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField fracy_tf;
    public static javax.swing.JComboBox fromwhat_combobox;
    public static javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane output_pane;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField x1_tf;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField x2_tf;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField y1_tf;
    public static javax.swing.JTextField y2_tf;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    /**
     * Action(s) performed below
     */

    public void calc_buttonAP(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(frac_checkbox.isSelected()) {
            try {    
                String a;
                a = x1_tf.getText().toString();
                double x1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                a = y1_tf.getText().toString();
                double y1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                a = x2_tf.getText().toString();
                double x2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                a = y2_tf.getText().toString();
                double y2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

                double Ax,Ay, x = 0,y = 0,nx,ny,fx = 0,fy = 0;
                double numerator = Integer.parseInt(fracx_tf.getText().toString());
                double denominator = Integer.parseInt(fracy_tf.getText().toString());

                if(fromwhat_combobox.getSelectedIndex()==0) {
                    Ax = Integer.parseInt(x1_tf.getText().toString());
                    Ay = Integer.parseInt(y1_tf.getText().toString());
                    x += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2));
                    y += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2));
                    //problem lies here ^^^^
                }
                else {
                    Ax = Integer.parseInt(x2_tf.getText().toString());
                    Ay = Integer.parseInt(y2_tf.getText().toString());
                    x += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2));
                    y += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ay, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Ax, 2));
                    //problem lies here ^^^^
                }

                nx = (x*numerator)/denominator;
                ny = (y*numerator)/denominator;
                fx = Ax + nx;

                if((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)>=0) {
                    fy = Ay + ny;
                }
                else {
                    fy = Ay - ny;
                }

                String answer = "("+fx+","+fy+") is "+numerator+"/"+denominator+" way from ";
                output_pane.setText(answer);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        else if(!frac_checkbox.isSelected()) {
            try {
            String a;
            a = x1_tf.getText().toString();
            double x1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

            a = y1_tf.getText().toString();
            double y1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

            a = x2_tf.getText().toString();
            double x2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

            a = y2_tf.getText().toString();
            double y2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

            double finalAnswer = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
            double var1 = x2-x1;
            double var2 = y2-y1;
            double var3 = Math.pow(var1, 2);
            double var4 = Math.pow(var2, 2);
            double var5 = var3+var4;
            String answer = "Formula : sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 )\n"
                          + "sqrt( ("+x2+" - "+x1+")^2 + ("+y2+" - "+y1+")^2 )\n"
                          + "sqrt( ("+var1+")^2 + ("+var2+")^2 )\n"
                          + "sqrt( "+var3+" + "+var4+" )\n"
                          + "sqrt( "+var5+" )\n"
                          + "answer = "+ finalAnswer;
            output_pane.setText(answer);
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    public void frac_checkboxAP(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(!frac_checkbox.isSelected()) {
            fracx_tf.setEnabled(false);
            fracy_tf.setEnabled(false);
            fromwhat_combobox.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(frac_checkbox.isSelected()) {

            fracx_tf.setEnabled(true);
            fracy_tf.setEnabled(true);
            fromwhat_combobox.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * EOF
     */
}
```

Comment: It's a much easier problem if you understand something about Euclidean geometry and vectors.

Comment: **what** is the issue?

Comment: how is the x and y point determined? I'm not seeing this in your question.

Comment: The issue is me not being able to calculate the distance between points, especially is they are in different quadrants

Comment: Are these points on a panel? Where exactly are these points coming from? Give a clear example.

Comment: @peeskillet x and y and my attempt the calculate the distance between points, and the points are simply given by the user. Nothing is graphed, or plotted, its simply output based on use input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the distance formula in java code

```
Math.sqrt( Math.pow( (p1.getX() - p2.getX()) , 2 )) - Math.pow( p1.getY() - p2.getY()) , 2)));
```

Read square root of x1 - x2 squared minus y1 - y2 squared

```
a = x1_tf.getText().toString();
double x1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

a = y1_tf.getText().toString();
double y1 = Integer.parseInt(a);

a = x2_tf.getText().toString();
double x2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

a = y2_tf.getText().toString();
double y2 = Integer.parseInt(a);

Math.sqrt( Math.pow( (x1 - x2) , 2 ) - Math.pow( (y1 - y2) , 2) );
```

See [Distance Formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php)

Comment: Thank you, I had to change up the formula a bit but this solved the puzzle thanks :)

Comment: Also, if you want the double value, you should use `Double.parseDouble()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: OH and yeah, I noticed I had the parenthesis wrong. Just fixed it in the answer.